# spark-submit parse [application-arguments] error in yarn-cluster

Tags: apache-spark

When i submit like this, and in my application

```
spark-submit --master spark://ip:7077 --class mainClass myjar.jar 10}}
```

it will print out

```
10}}
```

but when i submit like this

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class mianClass myjar.jar 10}}
```

it only print out

```
10
```

So where is the **"}}"**?  The same result when **"10}}}" "10}}}}"**

**My code:**

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println("start")
  println(args(0))
  println("args")
}
```

**Spark version is 2.1.0**

Comment: isn't `start` being printed?

Comment: yes, `start` and `args` are both printed.

Comment: did you try using "10}}" , are u on windows

Comment: No! On linux!  I was going to set the `application arguments` to one json. But at the end of json, it can not parse `}}`. So I specially test `10}}`.